# Turán density of hypergraphs with very few edges

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hypergraph, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-set-theory

As usual, for an $r$-uniform hypergraph $G$, denote by $ex_r(n,G)$ the maximum number of edges an $r$-uniform, $G$-free hypergraph on $n$ vertices can have, and let $\lim \frac{ex_r(n,G)}{\binom nr}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow\pi_r(G)$.
Define the maximum of this quantity over graphs with $m$ edges as $\pi_r(m)=\max \{\pi_r(G) : e(G)=m\}$.

> Is it true that $\lim \pi_r(m)\stackrel{r\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0$ for every $m$?

For $m=1,2$ this follows from well-known statements for set families, but I couldn't find anything for higher values.
On one hand, this feels like it should be simple, on the other, it seems to have strong consequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems, the answer is negative for $m=3$: consider $H = \{AB, BC, AC\}$ for disjoint $k$-element sets $A,B,C$. Then for $r=2k$ the is an $r$-graph $F$ which density is close to 0.5: consider only $r$-tuples that have an odd intersection with the first half-part $V_1$ of vertex set. Suppose there is a copy of $H$. Then at least two of sets $A,B,C$ have intersection with $V_1$ of the same parity. Union of two such sets do not belong to $F$; a contradiction.